# How to know which button the user selected on <paper-dialog>?

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

Given this simplified version of my template:

```
<template>
   <paper-dialog id='dialog_alert' heading="{{title}}">
     <p>{{alertText}}</p>
     <paper-button on-tap='{{btnAffirmative}}' label='Yes' affirmative autofocus></paper-button>
     <paper-button on-tap='{{btnNegative}}' label='No' dismissive></paper-button>
   </paper-dialog>
</template>
```

I'm having trouble finding how how to see which button the user selected after the dialog closes.  It doesn't appear that the dialog itself provides any event for it, so I just hooked "on-tap" events onto to the buttons and that seems to work.  However, when I use this approach the paper-button element throws up after the click:

> Uncaught Uncaught Error:
>
> Bad state: controller overlay-host is not a Dart polymer-element.

When I take the "on-tap" hooks out, no exception, but then I have no idea which button the user pressed.   I'm hoping I overlooked something obvious in the documentation.

I should note that, even with the exception, the program continues to execute fine, so I'm just rolling with using the on-tap events for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically your approach seems fine. The `affirmative`, `dismissive` attributes have only influence on where they are added to the dialog ([see where and how it is used in the source](https://github.com/Polymer/paper-dialog/blob/master/paper-dialog.html#L74) )

I suppose the error is caused by the Dart wrapper for the JS polymer elements. I would create a bug report at http://github.com/dart-lang/paper-elements.

You could try `on-click` instead of `on-tap` because `on-tap` is a polyfill event - just to be sure.

Comment: Tried the on-click idea.  Same exception is thrown.  I'll open an issue on it soon.